# To all r users, Logistic Regression Model

Tags: r

Sirs/Madam,
When I run this model:

```r
mylogit <- glm(lsd_OID ~ TWI + SPI + slope + roadDist + lithology +
                 landCover + hydroDist + geoThrust + drainageDensity +
                 curvature + aspect,
               data = "binomial")
```

Error comes:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = lsd_OID ~ TWI + SPI + slope + roadDist +  : 
  'data' must be a data.frame, environment, or list
```

I have used RStudio Version 1.3.1093, what is will be the problem?

Comment: For most R-related problems I see on SO, if I'm concerned about a version, it's about the packages being used or the version of R, almost never does the version of RStudio become a factor. RStudio != R.

Comment: `data` should be your dataframe not `"binomial"` use `?glm` to view the documentation and specify the correct arguments for the function

Answer (score 2):

your argument **data** should be the data frame where the variables come from, the family argument should be: family = "binomial"

like this:

```
mylogit <- 
glm(lsd_OID ~ TWI + SPI + slope + roadDist + lithology + landCover + 
hydroDist + geoThrust + drainageDensity + curvature + aspect,
data = "df_name", family = "binomial")
```

in this example, you should substitute "df_name" with the name of the data frame where your variables are.

Comment: I think `data` should not be in quotes, it should be `data = df_name`

Comment: In fact, I think having a string assigned to `data=` is what got us here in the first place ...

Comment: thanks,..i used this syntax mylogit<-glm(lsd_OID~TWI+SPI+slope+roadDist+lithology+landCover+hydroDist+geoThrust+drainageDensity+curvature+aspect,data=data.frame(),family="binomial")

Comment: But still an error: Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'lsd_OID' not found  I check my table seems everything is fine....???

Comment: @user21081 Using `data=data.frame()` will use an empty data.frame. What is the name of the data.frame that you loaded your data inro? How did you import your data into R?

Comment: mylogit <- glm(lsd_OID ~ TWI + SPI + slope + roadDist + lithology + landCover + hydroDist + geoThrust + drainageDensity + curvature + aspect, data = df_name("lsdData.csv"), family = "binomial")
Error in df_name("lsdData.csv") : could not find function "df_name"     I have imported by creating a project file, it is successfully added...still then problem,..plz help me.

Comment: Is there a function `df_name`? I've never heard of it. It sounds like there are some significant gaps in the tutorials or howtos you are using to learn how to use `glm` (and friends); if your data is a `data.frame` named `myframe`, then you would use `glm(..., data=myframe, family="binomial")`. It's difficult to provide much more than non-specific help like this without a reproducible question (we don't even know what your data is named much less what it looks like nor what it contains). I hope this helps you get past this hurdle.